# Android APK Auto Update

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know if this is possible.
Our users download & install APK from Play market the first time,
and afterward while the application detected that a new version is available, it can auto download & install new APK (using the same signature as original one) from our custom server, even if the allow side-loading setting is unchecked in user's device?

Or we must upload the new update APK on Play market again, and let user manually download & install from market?

thanks.

Comment: _"and let user manually download & install from market?"_ Not if the user has automatic updates enabled.

Comment: We want to ensure our user always running the latest version of application. So if a new version is available, we want to make our APK auto download & install the new updates. Even if they don't update it from store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has installed the app from Play Store then the **updates must come from Play Store only**. Otherwise there would be signature mismatch problem.

You need to change the "version code" and "version name" and upload new APKs to the Play Store again.

And user's do not need to manually download updates if they have "**automatic updates**" enabled.

**UPDATE**

I saw your last comment and just thought to help.

> We want to ensure our user always running the latest version of
>   application.

Yes, I can understand this requirement. The users who have "automatic updates" enabled (most of the users have) will automatically get the latest version of your app.

And those who don't, will get a notification to choose if they want to update now or postpone it later (may be they don't have enough internet data or time to download app app updates now).

**The Trick**

I can give you a trick. You can use your custom server to check if the user is currently using the latest version of the app or not. So if any user who is using the outdated version opens your app, the app checks to see that from the server and then prompts the user to update the app immediately. You can also take the user directly to the Play Store to update the app. Simple, isn't it?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is the automatic updates setting enabled by default?

Comment: Yes, Google Play Store will automatically update the apps  by default. The user may choose to uncheck this.

Comment: What if they disabled automiatic updates? How do we make sure they're running the latest application.

Comment: Thanks, your anwser is complete and helpful to me, and it's a good idea to prompt the user that there is a new update available and take them to store page of our app, even if they disabled the automatic updates.

Comment: @DogyCat Yes, that's the most elegant solution I could think of. If you need further help on this please post a new question and give me the link. And if this question was helpful, please upvote.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you please up vote it. Its the way of saying "thank you" in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Google Play Store update mechanism. It's the one and only way to deploy updates.

Some time ago Facebook also tried to implement their own update mechanism for their app and the result was Google temporary removing the app from the Play Store because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload the APK to the Play Store again. Depending no the user's settings he will auto-update the app or manually download the update from the store.

Comment: You can implement your own update mechanism, but you will only be able to update certain parts of your app. Depends on why you actually need this feature.

Comment: What exactly are you updating? If the updates are only content then you can do that. If the updates are actual infrastructure then you cannot.

Comment: Not only resource content, it may contain new feature or bug fixes.